# IIS Configurations to access site without adding the port number after the IP

Tags: iis, configuration, hosting, publish

there is a server which i can access it with IP:Port like 123.123.123.123:1111

**how can i configure a domain to refer to the site without the port number 1111 ?**
simply i want to make my domain refer to IP:port 
please help me to solve it

Comment: If you want your site to be accessible via default port (80 or 443), modify your site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background or set up a reverse proxy. There are tons of other articles over the internet on them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, each connection on the internet requires an IP address and a port.

For certain protocols, the client server, in this case a web browser knows the port for http or https and is automatically adding the port number 80 or 443 to the request to the server.

DNS server that resolve IP addresses have no concept of ports.

If you can't change the port on the IIS server to 80 or 443, you need to put something in front of it, a reverse proxy or another networking device that takes requests at ports 80 or 443 and forwards them to port 1111 on your IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 80 port which is the default port to resolve your issue. so if you do not want to show the port number in URL just set binding as shown below:

in the binding select your IP address from the drop-down, enter 80 port and your domain name if you want to add.

[image]

[image]

[image]